# How to temporarily move a django site into a subdirectory (for testing)?

Tags: python, django, url, .htaccess, fastcgi

I am in the process of deploying a new Django site to replace a current Wordpress blog.  As I get it setup, I want to test everything in the domain's subdirectory before I switch things to the root and "go live".  For example: `http://example.com/django/`

Editing my `.htaccess` file allows me to redirect things without a hitch (I can see the Django site and my wordpress site still works), however, I am not sure how to tell Django to view `http://example.com/django/` as the BASE URL (rather than just `http://example.com/`) ... I tried setting my SITE domain but that didn't help.

Currently, all my pages get a 404 response - they they aren't matching any url patterns (because none of my url patterns start with `django/`).

I looked for a way to set a `BASE_URL` but can't find any.  Ideas?  I only want to do this for a couple hours while I test everything to make sure it is working and then swap the settings in the `.htaccess` file and run it on the main site.

Answer (score 1):

Set the following in your Apache directive:

```
    PythonOption django.root /django
```

Then django will trim `/django` off the front of every URL request.

Comment: Hmm - I am on a shared host and using FastCGI and I don't believe I can edit my `httpd.conf` file ... do you know, off hand, how to do that with FastCGI ?  (I am googling but not seeing...)

Comment: Take a look at http://www.djangobook.com/en/beta/chapter21/#cn133. If you play around with what `ModRewrite` is doing there, that should work. Alternatively, you could set a `DJANGO_ROOT` in the settings file, and set up a middleware early in the stack that strips the location on each request as it comes in

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this would be to copy your current `mysite/mysite/urls.py` call it say `betaurls.py` to add `/django/` before each url, thus

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)
```

in `urls.py` would become

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^django/admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)
```

in the new file `betaurls.py` and then, in the `settings.py` file, alternate between

```
ROOT_URLCONF = 'mysite.urls'
```

and

```
ROOT_URLCONF = 'mysite.betaurls'
```

So `/django/` becomes your new root for the django deployment.